# What is SimAudioProcessorService taking up 35GB on my macos?

Tags: macos, xcode

What is this portly beast taking up over twice the RAM I have
[image]

Comment: Google thinks it's part of Xcode/iOS simulator. Can't find much more than that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377095/xcodebuild-test-could-not-launch-simulator-10827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of Xcode. The memory column you show isn't immediately helpful for most cases I've seen - what does the information (circle with an i above the value of 36 GB) show for Real / Virtual / Shared and Private memory size?

You can power down that simulator and free all the memory with the command line tool `xcrun simctl shutdown` command for the applicable simulator that was started on your Mac.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes